# Laptop does not start when it has a dvd with linux iso file inside

Tags: windows-10, boot, ubuntu-14.04

I want to install ubuntu alongside windows 10. In order to do that I have made a blank partition for ubuntu and now I want to boot from the dvd which has the iso file inside.However, when I power on the laptop having the dvd inside and fast startup disabled and secure boot disabled it does not start..
What it does is that the screen goes blank and it does not show anything!

This is a picture of my bios (uefi) boot order:
[image: This is a picture of my bios (uefi) boot order]

Comment: Did you put the iso file as a file on the disk or did you burn the iso to the disk? Did you setup your system to boot from a disc?

Comment: @Seth I put the iso file in the disk and I haven't setup the system to boot from the disk. (I haven't this proccess again)

Comment: download magiciso and burn the iso to the dvd. then set to boot from cd in the bios.

Comment: @m0atz I first had the iso file in my dvd using rufus, but it had no result.. When I just put the iso in the dvd I have the results described previously (blank screen).. So, probably it is better to just drop the iso inside the disk. However, I'll try burning it..

Comment: yeh, it needs to be mounted in order for the computer to boot from it.

Comment: Did it work ? what is your Laptop Brand/Model/Series ?

Answer (score 0):

Rufus (which you already have installed) is the recommended application at the official Ubuntu website for making a bootable live Ubuntu USB on Windows. The flash drive you use should be 2GB or larger and formatted to FAT32. For Ubuntu 18.04 and later it should be 4GB or larger. Any cheap flash drive will do, and you can even use a borrowed flash drive since they're rewritable. The formatting procedure will delete all of the files that are already on the flash drive.

The instructions for preparing an Ubuntu live USB are found at the official Ubuntu [How to create a bootable USB stick...](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) webpage (see the step-by-step instructions below).

1. Open Rufus and select your USB stick in the *Device* dropdown menu.

   [image: IMG:]
2. Click the CD-ROM icon next to the *FreeDOS* dropdown menu, then find your downloaded Ubuntu ISO and click *Open* and then *Start*.

   [image]
3. Click *Yes* when it asks to download Syslinux software.

   [image]
4. Click *OK* to write in ISO Image mode.

   [image]
5. Confirm that your USB stick is selected and then click *OK* to continue. It is **very important** to verify that the device that you are installing the Ubuntu live USB to is indeed your flash drive, so that you don't overwrite any of your system or personal files which may make your operating system unbootable.

   [image]
6. When it is finished, just restart your computer and start using Ubuntu, or you can install Ubuntu.

   [[image]

The Ubuntu live USB flash drive that you make this way will be bootable from a PC. In order to enable your computer to boot from the USB flash drive, you must enter your BIOS menu by pressing one of these keys: <kbd>Delete</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> as soon as the motherboard splash screen appears when the computer is booting. In the BIOS menu, you need to change the boot order so that the USB flash drive, which is usually called USB-HDD in newer computers, is the first entry in the boot sequence, and then save your new BIOS settings and exit the BIOS setup.

The Ubuntu USB made with Rufus boots successfully in a virtual machine, however it does not boot from the physical laptop and neither DVD or USB devices can be selected as boot options in the Boot Option Priorities of the Setup Utility. So there is a problem configuring the Setup Utility.

Comment: I cannot find my usb in the bootorder. I can only find Windows Boot Manager and some Realtek stuff..

Comment: There might be the problem. In your UEFI/BIOS setup utility can you find the DVD? Sometimes if you delete one of the three items from the boot order in the UEFI/BIOS you can choose a different device.

Comment: no I cannot find either the usb or the DVD.. I am affraid of deleting items from boot order, because I do not know what will happen next.. For example, what will happen if I disable the Windows Boot Mananer?

Comment: I will try to upload one in a few minutes

Comment: I uploaded the picture. Check the edit in my question.

Comment: I disabled it, but it does not give the usb or dvd options, so I cannot choose to boot from them. Not to mention that I have tried booting from usb in Virtual Machine and it works! But, in the computer it doesn't..